# SQL trend over time

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a table with two columns, date and score. I want to find something like:

- Sum as of 7 days ago
- Sum as of 6 days ago
- ...
- Sum as of today

An individual thing could be found with

```
select sum(score) from my_table
where date <= DateAdd("d", -1, getdate)
```

But I would like to not have to run a new query every time.

(I am using django, but pure SQL solutions are fine too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statements to sum each value you care about.

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN date <= DateAdd("d", -1, getdate) THEN score ELSE 0 END) as sum1,
(CASE WHEN date <= DateAdd("d", -2, getdate) THEN score ELSE 0 END) as sum2, etc.
```

Comment: I was hoping that there was a more elegant way than just putting a bajillion case statements. Oh well.

Comment: @Xodarap What about summing and grouping by day.  Then in code when you read in the results adding each day up.